# Column sorting not working

Tags: sort-order

I have civicrm 4.4.2. When I try to order any search result by other columns, I always get the same message:

> *No matches found for:
>   Contacts IN Administrators AND Group Status - "Added"
>   Suggestions:
>       check your spelling
>       try a different spelling or use fewer letters
>       if you are searching within a Group or for Tagged contacts, try 'any group' or 'any tag'
>       add a New Individual, Organization or Household
>       make sure you have enough privileges in the access control system*

I have tried with Firefox 31.5, with IE9, and Chrome 47.0. When I click the different columns, a parameter appears in the ULR ...&crmSID=4_u The only one working is the default one &crmSID=1_u (first column).

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should start by upgrading to the latest version in the [4.4 series](https://civicrm.org/download).  (4.4.20).

The problem you refer to sounds like a bug that was fixed in a later point version of the 4.4 series. We are using 4.4 and can sort successfully by all but State.